# Is there any way to import Azure Blob Services Package in Snowpark

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage, snowpark

I've created the python script which read the excel file from azure blob storage and parse into multiple CSV files. The script is working fine in python. But I try to run the same file using snowpark it throws the error as "Modulenotfound" for azure blob service package

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check if the package is supported:

[Displaying Available Packages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-packages.html#displaying-available-packages)

> You can display all packages available and their version information by querying the PACKAGES view in the Information Schema.
>
> ```
> select * from information_schema.packages where language = 'python';
> ```

Second, accessing network or file system is restricted:

[Downloading Data On Demand From Data Science Libraries](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-packages.html#downloading-data-on-demand-from-data-science-libraries)

> However, on-demand downloading does not work with Python UDFs due to Snowflake security constraints, **which disable some capabilities, such as network access and writing to files.**
>
> To work around this issue, download the data to your local environment and then provide it to the UDF via a Snowflake stage.

[Following Good Security Practices](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-designing.html#following-good-security-practices)

> Network access.
>
> Because your code cannot access the network directly or indirectly, you cannot use the code in the Snowflake Python Connector to access the database. Your UDF cannot itself act as a client of Snowflake.